# Binding function with more arguments than needed and passing definite arguments to it

Tags: c++, boost, boost-bind

Let I have a function

```
void f1(type_a a, type_b b, type_c c)
```

I want to convert it to

```
void f2(type_a a, type_b b)
```

where instead of c will be passed my object.

How can I do this usind boost:bind?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this I think

```
boost::bind(&f1, _1, _2, c_default_value);
```

Comment: I tried, but recieved a compiller error "error: invalid use of 'void'"

Comment: @w00drow on which line?
`type_c c_default_value;
boost::bind(&f1, _1, _2, c_default_value)(a, b);`

Answer (score 0):

C++ is not a functional language, so you can't make a true partial application of a function. What you can do is the following:

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
void f1(int a, double b, char c)
{}
int main()
{
  auto binder = boost::bind(&f1, _1, _2, 'c');
  binder(1, 2.0);
}
```

Note however, that while you can pass `binder` to any context where a *callable* is expected, it is *not* convertible to a pointer-to-function.